# xmount permission issue

Tags: mount, permissions, fuse

I'm having a problem loading an image in VirtualBox after mounting the file using xmount.

Here's the command that I used:
xmount --in aff --out vdi win.aff imagefile

After running the above command the imagefile appears as a mount folder

When i try to load the the image win.vdi in virtualbox it gives me the following error:
Failed to open image 'home/mylinux/testwin/imagefile/win.vdi' for writing due to wrong permissions (VERR_VD_IMAGE_READ_ONLY).

However, if I drag the win.vdi to my desktop then i'm able to change the permission and load the image correctly in virtualbox.

I'm not sure if this related in fuse.conf I have also added:
user_allow_other

I'm still new to xmount and fuse, apologize in advance if I mentioned anything wrong.